# https, Jquery, PHP, Curl and document.cookie

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, curl, https

First off what I am trying to do:
I am trying to access a login page so that I can log in. The site is Https and requires cookies to be set so I am using jquery to run a PHP + Curl to get that page for me and store the cookies. Well I have been able to get the cookies but I keep getting a popup that Cookies are not set. So I looked at it a lot more and found that javascript does an initial check to see cookies are enabled:

```
function initLogin(){
// check if cookie is enabled so applications can run
if (document.cookie == "") {
alert("Cookies are disabled. Cannot access mid-tier with this setting.\nPlease configure your browser to accept cookies.");
return;
} 
....Other Code... 
}
```

I have looked through just about every post on this forum and tried a crap load of different code but no luck. So the question is how to get past this point? My understading is: Jquery calls the php script on the proxy/server and calls curl to get me the webpage. Curl will then save the cookies for later use but how do you use them. I thought just by setting them in a cookie file would be sufficient but I guess I was wrong. So I tired just setting them to CURLOPT_COOKIE but I dont know if this is correct.

Here is a copy of the code that I am running:

```
function getpage(){
$fullurl = "https://url/arsys/shared/login.jsp?/arsys/home";

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullurl);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

preg_match_all('|Set-Cookie: (.*);|U', $output, $results);    
$newcookies = implode(';', $results[1]);
echo "<br>COOKIES:" . $newcookies;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $newcookies);
echo curl_error($ch) . " " . $output;
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Output from above code:
COOKIES:JSESSIONID=B4830242479D3DFD3235D17EE6A4DEB8;q=""HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=B4830242479D3DFD3235D17EE6A4DEB8; Path=/arsys; Secure Set-Cookie: q=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/ Date: Fri, 20 Apr 2012 17:57:17 GMT Content-Length: 35657

I also tried:

```
function getpage(){
$ckfile = "cookies/cookie.txt";
$fullurl = "https://url/arsys/shared/login.jsp?/arsys/home";

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fullurl);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

The cookies get saved in the correct file but still get the same message.

I tried the code on google and it works fine its the javascript that is stopping me..

Answer (score 0):

You must store the cookies in the browser cookies (after storing it in separated file) after getting it from curl by using [PHP setcookie](http://php.net/setcookie) to be able to use it via JavaScript.

JavaScript side: After setting cookies using PHP it's better to use [jQuery.cookies.js](http://cookies.googlecode.com/files/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.min.js.zip)

```
$.cookies.get()

$.cookies.filter()

$.cookies.set()

$.cookies.del()

$.cookies.test()

$.cookies.setOptions()
```